# I'm getting this error :'Data type not supported:Address , List<sobject> be displayed in VFpage

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

```
List<sObject>  SObjectListToShow = Database.query(query);
```

**In Visual force page:**

```
<apex:page controller="SearchListController">
    <apex:form >
               <apex:pageBlock id="result" >
          <apex:inputText value="{!objectName }"/>
           <apex:commandButton action="{!getObjField}" value="GO" />
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SObjectListToShow }" var="res">//res holds record id for given sObject(try this like list.field name)
              <apex:repeat value="{!objectFields}" var="field">// this list contains field names
                    <apex:column value="{!res[field]}"/>
               </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You are going to have to provide more context around your code as the error does not make sense in the context you have provided. All I can say is that it appears you are trying to assign a value to the Account Address field and this is not supported as it is a compound field or Address is part of your query

Answer (score 1):

I am going to guess (due to limited code snippet) this is the issue:

Address is a compound field and cannot be queried via the Address type.

SEE: http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/compound_fields_address.htm

So in your query instead of using `Select Address from Account`

use: `[Select billingstreet, billingstate, ....... From Account]`